# how to convert this array into Hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array something like this

```
['project','AAA','Division','BBB','TestingType','CCC','Email','abc@gmail.com','def'@gmail.com','efg@gmail.com',...]
```

the email count varies. and also something may enter inside like `'project','AAA','Time','2323','Division','BBB','TestingType','CCC'` Now you might have noticed that Time and 2323 entered so result hash must consist of 'Time'=>'2323' as well. But Email anyway would be at the end.

I want to convert this array into a hash like this

```
resultHash = {
  'project' => 'AAA',
  'Division' => 'BBB',
  'TestingType' => 'CCC',
  'Email' => ['abc@gmail.com', 'def@gmail.com', 'efg@gmail.com']
}
```

The difficulty here for me is, email count varies every time. Can someone help to convert this array into a desired hash as given above?

Comment: Is the order of the array fixed? I.e. project, division testintype an email are always there and will always be in this order?

Comment: @Shimu Hi, I updated the question now which explains very clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something like:

```
attributes, emails = *array.slice_before('Email')
Hash[*attributes].update(emails.first => emails[1..-1])
#=> {"project"=>"AAA", "Division"=>"BBB", "TestingType"=>"CCC", 
#    "Email"=>["abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com", "efg@gmail.com"]}
```

Comment: @ilya great answer. thanks for `slice_before` method. I was about to post `Hash[*(array[0..(array.index('Email')-1)])].merge({'Email'=>array[(array.index('Email')+1)..-1]})` x-D

Answer (score 1):

Just for having another option:

```
ary[ary.index('Email')..].partition{ |e| e == 'Email'}
.then { |k, v| ary[0..ary.index('Email')-1].each_slice(2).to_a << [k.first, v] }.to_h

#=> {"project"=>"AAA", "Division"=>"BBB", "TestingType"=>"CCC", "Email"=>["abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com", "efg@gmail.com"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['project','AAA','Division','BBB','TestingType','CCC',
       'Email','abc@gmail.com','def@gmail.com','efg@gmail.com']

idx = arr.index('Email')
  #=> 6 
Hash[*arr[0,idx], 'Email', arr[idx+1..-1]]
  #=> {"project"=>"AAA", "Division"=>"BBB", "TestingType"=>"CCC",
  #    "Email"=>["abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com", "efg@gmail.com"]}
```

Comment: Hi, spat operator is used to expand the array ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, yes. (I'd make my reply longer but there is really nothing more to say.)

Comment: Thank you. I understood.